# How to send the data using Eclipse Milo OPC Server

Tags: opc-ua, milo

I want to send data generated by my application to OPC UA client using OPC UA Server. I have gone through Eclipse Milo Project which is great resource for the same. But I don't know how to integrate it in our Application.The Application produces output in JSON format. The data of multiple nodes is stored, processed and sent using JSON format like following.

```
{"deviceId":"36860","timestamp":"2019-03-07 10:37:20+05:30","1":"228.6","2":"237.65","3":"237.21","4":"0.13","5":"0.0","6":"0.11","7":"-2.95","8":"0.0","9":"4.03","10":"22.2","11":"0.0","12":"16.43","13":"-21.83","14":"0.0","15":"-15.72","16":"-0.13","17":"1.0","18":"0.25","19":"262.35","20":"0.0","21":"284.18","22":"234.49","23":"703.47","24":"0.08","25":"0.24","26":"0.36","27":"1.08","28":"12.87","29":"38.62","30":"-12.52"}
```

where 36860 is the nodeId/deviceId, timestamp is the time when data is captured from the node rest are the Parameter Ids and their actual reading values of node in key value pair. 
How to use the ExampleServer to send this data and How client would receive it ?
If possible can anyone provide an example ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the first think you should decide is how to model the data in the server.

You could of course stuff that String into a single VariableNode with DataType of String but then why bother using OPC UA?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Kevin. We want our system to be OPC Compliant that's why we are going to implement it. I am newbie to OPC. Can you please tell me how to do that if I have multiple nodes with any example ?